# Is it possible to keep clearing the client's clipboard data using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, clipboard

I want to know that Is it possible to keep clearing the client's clipboard data using vbscript from a webpage until he closes that page.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this (code adapted from the code on this [page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/12/15/how-can-i-grab-a-url-from-the-clipboard-and-then-open-that-web-site-in-a-browser.aspx)) might work:

```
Do Until 1 = 0
    Set ie = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Navigate "about:blank"
    ie.document.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "text", ""
    ie.Quit
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop
```

Though I'd assume (or at least hope) that the user would get security warnings about this and if this was for a webpage on the open internet I'd see it as malicious since I usually open web pages and leave them open while I continue with other work and would find it incredibly annoying if my clipboard got overwritten once a second.